# setlocal enabledelayedexpansion in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /F "skip=2 tokens=2*" %%A IN ('REG QUERY "HKLM\Software\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\1.6" /v JavaHome') DO set JavaPath=%%B
SETX -m JAVA_HOME "%JavaPath%"
ECHO java__path variable: !JavaPath!
ECHO java__path: %JAVA_HOME%
```

- Am setting java home from registry.
- the values is getting set.
- SETX is working.

when i try echo using `!JavaPath!`, am getting value and when i tried echo `%JAVA_HOME%`, the value is empty.

I tried with `enabledelayedexpansion` also but no use. How to echo `%JAVA_HOME%`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the setx with another set to reset the local variable.

```
SETX -m JAVA_HOME "%JavaPath%"
SET "JAVA_HOME=%JavaPath%"
```

If these are all within another loop then use !variable! syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be setting `JavaPath` from the value of `JavaHome` (no underscore) in the registry.

`SETX` AFAIAA `WRITES` the value into the registry but does not assign the value to the variable.

The value in `JAVA_HOME` in the registry would be available to FUTURE sessions, but not already-established sessions.